# c# - polymorphism Printing only 1 class object from the polymorphism list

Tags: c#, polymorphism

How do i print only 1 class from my polymorphism list?
For example you have a polymorphism list in the program.cs

```
List<Person> personList = new List<Person>();

static void DisplayVisitor(List<Person> pList)
        {
            foreach (Person p in pList)
            {
                if (p.Equals(Visitor))
                    Console.WriteLine(p);
            }
        }
```

I have Resident and Visitor classes in the Person class. I already create a couple of Residents and Visitors but how do I display only the visitors from my person list.
How do i check for the Visitor object inside the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`is`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#is-operator) operator to check p is of `Visitor` type or not.

> The is operator checks if the runtime type of an expression result is
> compatible with a given type.

```
foreach (Person p in pList)
   {
         if (p is Visitor visitorObj)
              Console.WriteLine(visitorObj);   //I believe you have overridden `ToString()` method
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use operator [`is`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is) to check type of object

```
if (p is Visitor v) // with type pattern
  Console.WriteLine(v);
```

Note that you can filter list with Linq method `OfType<T>` to get only items of specific type:

```
foreach(var v in pList.OfType<Visitor>())
   Console.WriteLine(v);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers you can use the is like this

```
    static void DisplayVisitor(List<Person> pList)
    {
        foreach (Person p in pList)
        {
            if (p is Visitor)
                Console.WriteLine(p);
        }
    }
```